# Storing strings in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to save some input values inside the local storage, the inputs are players names, I want to store them all, so I can use them later.
This is what I'm trying:

```
const input = document.querySelectorAll("[type='text'][id^='player']");

for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem('playersNames', String(input[i].value));
};
```

Comment: input value is always string. you don't need to convert them

Comment: A single key can only store one value.

Comment: The loop will fail. Each time, the new value for the cookie will overwrite the existing value and at last you'll have only one name. Either you can store them as separate cookies or a single string with some kind of unique separator.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify to store an array

Comment: @Arcteezy how can I store them in a single string ?